# Need good grid based on jQuery with requirements below

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, grid

Can somebody recommend a good jQuery grid implementation with the following possibilities.

1. Header columns can be grouped
2. Columns' order can be modified with drag-n-drop
3. In-line editing with possibility to edit the whole row and navigate over editable field with TAB key or/with arrows.
4. Good keyboard support with general features like editing, page navigation, adding/deleting row.
5. And for sure dynamic data source support get via JSON strings and dynamic column's quantity could be set.
6. and the last requirement is that it should not be licensed under GPL2 but can be under lGPL2 for instance.

I've found a good one DataTables with features 1,2, partly 3 and 4. The bad is the in-line editing when u can edit only one cell at once and u should press ENTER or ESC to finish and proceed to the next one.

So I'm advanced with your help:D
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqgrid is really nice and have a good documentation.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:download

Comment: yeah, it's a quite good grid, but it doesn't have colspan feature (header cells grouping) and drag'n'drop columns reorder.

Comment: It have both. Check the demos http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax) mvc grid

In response to your comment please take time to read the t&c's

> The Telerik
>   Extensions for ASP.NET MVC come in both an open source and a
>   commercial version to help you find the best option for your projects’
>   requirements. The open source version, available also on CodePlex,
>   provides you with the entire source code and all updates of Telerik’s
>   three major releases every year. This option is the perfect solution
>   for any GPLv2-compatible app

Comment: and is possible to find something free?

Comment: Did you read the website/license terms.....

Comment: thanks for your response, but I can't use this component under gpl v2 license since.

Comment: @drunkcamel - but in your question you talked about datatables which is GPL v2 and did not mention the license terms as an issue....! Edit your question stating the exact license terms you need in order for people to help you out

Comment: I've updated the question and is there any answer?

Comment: dunno, google is your friend!